# Jquery datatable dataTables_length

Tags: jquery, css

I am using Jquery data-table  and there is an option to show the "dataTables_length" drop down,

The drop down is located in `<div class="col-xs-6"` and i have no control of that..

My goal is to float the drop-down right but is is getting float in the current div and not the whole page

The circle is the place i want it to appear, the line separation is the right of the `"col-xs-6` class:

[Img attached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I9HL7.png)

---

```
  function initCompanyTable() {
    //self.$eventsTable = $('#events_table');
    oTable = $tblManagedUsers.dataTable({
        destroy: true,
        iDisplayLength: 10,
        // Show length rows menu
        "bLengthChange": true,
        // Hide search box
        "bFilter": false,
        //"sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
        "oLanguage": {
            "sLengthMenu": "_MENU_ records",
            "oPaginate": {
                "sPrevious": "Prev",
                "sNext": "Next"
            }
        },
        //set words to show

        "aoColumns": [
            null,       // DATE & TIME
            null,       // COMPANY
            null,       // LEVEL
            null,       // USERNAME
            null        // IP ADDRESS

        ],
        "aoColumnDefs": [
            {
                'bSortable': true,
                'aTargets': [0]
            }
        ]
    })

    oTable.fnDraw();
}
```

Comment: You don't say which version you're using, but if 1.9, you can use [`sDom`](http://legacy.datatables.net/usage/options#sDom)

Comment: @ markpsmith i am using - 1.10, what can i do?

Answer (score 1):

This section shows what you are looking for:

https://datatables.net/reference/option/dom#Markup

You can surround the dropdown in a css class or an id and then apply the appropriate styling to the dom object.  Try this in your dom option when initializing the DataTable:

```
dom: '&lt;"float-correctly"l&gt;frtip'
```

Then apply css to the class `float-correctly`.

Comment: where do i add this line? `dom: '&lt;"float-correctly"l&gt;frtip'` in the data table init? I added this line to there and it duplicated the drop-down X4

Comment: Could you post your full datatables init config?